# Twitter Bootstrap, Nav-Bar and Laravel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

I'm doing an application using Laravel and I want to use twitter bootstrap.

I'm using Laravel 4.1 and Boottstrap 3.1.1

I want to have a nav-bar so I did this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Authentication App With Laravel 4</title>

    {{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
    {{ HTML::style('css/main.css')}}
</head>

<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav">  
                    @if(!Auth::check())
                        <li>{{ HTML::link('users/register', 'Register') }}</li>   
                        <li>{{ HTML::link('users/login', 'Login') }}</li>   
                    @else
                        <li>{{ HTML::link('users/logout', 'logout') }}</li>
                    @endif
                </ul>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>              

    <div class="container">
        @if(Session::has('message'))
            <p class="alert">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
        @endif

        {{ $content }}
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this css in main.css

```
body {
padding-top: 40px;
}

.form-signup, .form-signin {
width: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

But I got this

[image]

The nav-bar looks bad, and I don't know what to do to have my nav-bar looking normal.

The css is not working properly, and I don't know why.

Any clues on what the problem might be?

Comment: It looks like you are referring to a pre version 3 of Bootstrap for your example.  The class "navbar-inner" was removed in version 3.  Try looking at some of the examples on the bootstrap site for up to date examples. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

Comment: Yeah you are right. I saw things in old docs. It's working properly now.
Thanks a lot @JaceRhea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class of navbar-nav to your ul:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">  
    @if(!Auth::check())
         <li>{{ HTML::link('users/register', 'Register') }}</li>   
         <li>{{ HTML::link('users/login', 'Login') }}</li>   
    @else
         <li>{{ HTML::link('users/logout', 'logout') }}</li>
    @endif
</ul>
```

I found this here:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Maybe you used some old docs

Comment: Yes the problem was because I saw things in old docs. My mistake. 
Thanks.